# Have CLI/batch dataloader process multiple files e.g. *.csv

Tags: data-loader, commandline, data-import

Before I go down start creating something or going down another path / solution, I am hoping someone has a done this already and can share.

I have my process-confg.xml file which references one CSV file. When I execute batch dataloader process I want to use a wild card *.csv and process all files until done.

```
<beans>
    <bean id="TestMultipleFiles" class="com.salesforce.dataloader.process.ProcessRunner" singleton="false">
        <description>Created by Dataloader Cliq.</description>
        <property name="name" value="TestMultipleFiles"/>
        <property name="configOverrideMap">
            <map>
                <entry key="dataAccess.name" value="/Users/mikegill/Dropbox/dataloader/cliq_process/TestMultipleFiles/read/*.csv"/>
                <entry key="dataAccess.readUTF8" value="true"/>
                <entry key="dataAccess.type" value="csvRead"/>
```

Anyone can help?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Sounds like you want to take all of them and perhaps add them to a list for processing?

Comment: thought about something like this for /R c:\test\src %i IN (​​*.*​​) DO (
MOVE %i C:\test\dest
YourBatch.bat C:\test\dest\%~nxi
)